# How can I get self.fields element value in forms file?

Tags: python, django, forms

In my `forms.py` file I have method called `r_valid` and it is used in views.py file.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.r_valid()
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Created Account for {username}!')
            return redirect('main')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

The meaning of it is to ad few more barriers for user which is creating an account. The problem is that in browser it returns an error =>

```
TypeError at /register/
'CharField' object is not subscriptable
```

Here you can see that problem is that I can't get `self.fields['username']`. So please explain how can I get the username value.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def r_valid(self):
        j = self.fields['username']

        if j[0] in '0123456789':
            raise ValidationError('The username can\'t start with number')
        
        if len(j) < 6:
            raise ValidationError('That username is too short')

        for c in j:
            if c in '@+-/':
                raise ValidationError('Your username can\'t contain @, +, - or /')
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].help_text = ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `self.cleaned_data['username']` to get the value of the field, but I suggest doing that kind of validation inside the forms [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) (or [`clean_username()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)) method.

```
def clean_username(self):
    s = self.cleaned_data['username']

    if s[0] in '0123456789':
        raise ValidationError('The username can\'t start with number')
    
    if len(s) < 6:
        raise ValidationError('That username is too short')

    for c in s:
        if c in '@+-/':
            raise ValidationError('Your username can\'t contain @, +, - or /')
```

---

Note: instead of `'0123456789'` you can also use [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#string.digits).

```
import string

if s[0] in string.digits:
    ...
```

Comment: Ralf thank you for your answer) But I am sorry, this is my first question and I dont have reputation so cant even like this answer

Answer (score 0):

You should override the form's `clean` method to add custom validation to the form. You can access the form's data there, and add your own validation:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(AddProfileForm, self).clean()
    username = cleaned_data.get('username')

    if username[0] in '0123456789':
        raise ValidationError('The username can\'t start with number')

    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: twrought I coultdnt like your answer, because my reputation is not >= 15. But thanks

Comment: @BareTalk no worries, im glad you found your answer!